# How to make Primefaces Growl stack messages?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

CommandButton displays the growl. But the previous growl message is lost. How can make growl display messages stack?

For example:

```
<h:form> 
    <p:growl id="growl" showDetail="true" life="6000" />  
    <p:commandButton value="Show" actionListener="#{growlView.showMessage}" update="growl" />  
</h:form>
```

And bean function:

```
public void showMessage() {
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage("Hello"));
}
```

I click button every second. I expect that messages will store and display  for 6 seconds. 
But after click button, previous message hides and i see only current message.

When i debugging i have that:

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getMessageList().size() == 0
```

I tried

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getFlash().setKeepMessages(true);
```

than

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>org.primefaces.messagePersistence</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
```

But is doesn't work =(

Please help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is not currently possible. Actually, it was the default behaviour back in 2011 (having stacked growl messages) but the primefaces core team has decided to:

> hide previous messages before displaying new ones on ajax update

Source: https://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/detail?id=1925

However, an issue was created [here](https://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/detail?id=7502) (October 2014) to bring back this feature but has not been reviewed yet.

Answer (score 4):

An simple solution using the primefaces 5.1 for those who want to display messages on a stack manner in the same `p:growl` without hide the previous messages is to override the default behavior of the component adding a primefacesFixes.js file to the classpath and override the function with the commented line below:

primefacesFixes.js:

```
PrimeFaces.widget.Growl.prototype.show = function(b) {
var a = this;
this.jq.css("z-index", ++PrimeFaces.zindex);
//this.removeAll(); //Commenting this line prevents an ajax update tho the <p:growl> from erasing global messages
$.each(b, function(c, d) {
    a.renderMessage(d);
});
```

};

So you call the fixes file like this on your template  tag:

```
<h:outputScript name="javascript/primefacesFixes.js" target="head" />
```

And can use only one `p:growl` on the page to render all the needed messages.

Answer (score 1):

Posting this on a old question, but this may be one solution (although, I'm on PFv6.2):

```
<p:growl id="messages" showDetail="true" keepAlive="true"/>
```

Simply add the `keepAlive="true"` to the growl element.